# INSERT INTO using WHERE

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert

I'm trying to insert the `JobNo` and `CellNo` columns that are not in `Table_1` from `View_1`. I wrote this query & I get an error.

Please help me out in correcting this.

I'm using SQL Server 2008

```
INSERT INTO Table_1(ID, JobNo, CellNo)
   SELECT View_1.ID, View_1.JobNo, View_1.CellNo
   FROM View_1
   WHERE View_1.JobNo 
   AND View_1.CellNo NOT IN (SELECT JobNo, CellNo FROM Table_1)
```

Comment: If you get an error - **please tell us what it is!** Just telling us you're getting one doesn't help....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is your `WHERE` clause - you can't compare sets of fields like this.  **You can only compare a single field at a time.**

Try instead:

```
WHERE View_1.JobNo NOT IN(SELECT JobNo FROM Table_1) 
AND View_1.CellNo NOT IN (SELECT CellNo FROM Table_1)
```

Alternatively you can use a single `EXISTS` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table_1(ID, JobNo, CellNo)
SELECT View_1.ID, View_1.JobNo, View_1.CellNo
FROM View_1 v
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table_1 t
                  WHERE t.JobNo = v.JobNo
                  AND t.CellNo = v.CellNo)
```

Comment: Some DBMS allow conditions like: `(View_1.JobNo, View_1.CellNo) NOT IN (SELECT JobNo, CellNo FROM Table_1)` - which is of course different than your query. My guess is that the OP wants soemthing equivalent with tthat, that works on SQL-Server.

Comment: @ypercube - I added an `EXISTS` as you were typing that :)

Comment: +1 for the `exists`. Was just about to post that one. Perhaps you should mention that your queries is not equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using SQL Server 2008, you can make use of the [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb510625.aspx) statement:

```
MERGE INTO Table_1 dst
USING (
  SELECT View_1.ID, View_1.JobNo, View_1.CellNo
  FROM View_1
) src
ON src.JobNo = dst.JobNo
AND src.CellNo = dst.CellNo
WHEN NOT MACHED THEN INSERT (ID, JobNo, CellNo)
  VALUES (src.ID, src.JobNo, src.CellNo)
```

I personally find a `MERGE` statement more concise than `INSERT .. SELECT .. WHERE`.